# Vertical allign, giving me th same headache

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Hi im trying to vertically align anchor text in a h1, ive tried vertical-align middle and few line height tricks cant get it working!

```
<header>
<div></div>
<h1><a>somelink</a></h1>
</header>
```

css:

```
div{
height:80px;
width:80px;
float:left;
}

h1{
      font-size: 32px;
      line-height: 32px;
      min-height: 80px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      a{
        line-height: inherit;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
```

Here is what im aiming for, I could probably solve it with  table, but theres lots of debate on whether tables should be used so im trying to find an alternative:

[image]

Comment: Why didn't a `line-height` trick work? If the `<div>` and `<h1>` are of known heights, just set the `line-height` to that height. Please explain what isn't working in more detail

Comment: Line height only works for single line.

Comment: Then you needed to state in your question that multi-line headings are required. It's often assumed that single lines are expected

Comment: Apologies, i've solved it for now, ive set header to display:table-row and the div/h1 to display table-cell against my better judgement. Not the best solution but if someone would like to offer their knowledge ill change it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xCh2w/)

You can add one `parent div` for this :-

```
 <div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>        
    <h1><a>somelink is here.somelink is here.somelink is here.somelink is here.somelink is here.somelink is here.somelink is here.somelink is here.</a></h1>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
#child {
    height:200px;
    width:80px;
    float:left;
    background: #333333;
}
#parent{
    border:solid 1px yellow;
    width: 100%;
```